# How to play sound in many devices at the same time

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I want to play sound in three external sound cards at the same time,I mean when I click in a button I can hear sound from three speakers which are related to my three sound cards.
I have a function but it plays sound only in one device,the first one it finds,I mean in this code the first device is number 0,so it play sound in it,but if you write device number 1 at first,it will play sound in it,as a conclusion it plays sound only in one device,it dont works for all the devices at the same time.
This is its code:

```
public void playAllAvailableDevices()
{
//create a new class for each wav file & output etc.
WaveOut waveOut1 = new WaveOut();
WaveFileReader waveReader1 = new WaveFileReader(fileName);
WaveOut waveOut2 = new WaveOut();
WaveFileReader waveReader2 = new WaveFileReader(fileName);
WaveOut waveOut3 = new WaveOut();
WaveFileReader waveReader3 = new WaveFileReader(fileName);

switch (waveOutDevices)
{
case 1: 
waveOut1.Init(waveReader1);
waveOut1.DeviceNumber = 0;
waveOut1.Play();
break;
case 2: 
waveOut1.Init(waveReader1);
waveOut1.DeviceNumber = 0;
waveOut1.Play();

waveOut2.Init(waveReader2);
waveOut2.DeviceNumber = 1;
waveOut2.Play();
break;
case 3:
waveOut1.Init(waveReader1);
waveOut1.DeviceNumber = 0;
waveOut1.Play();

waveOut2.Init(waveReader2);
waveOut2.DeviceNumber = 1;
waveOut2.Play();

waveOut3.Init(waveReader3);
waveOut3.DeviceNumber = 2;
waveOut3.Play();
break;
}}
```

fileName is the name of the sound file I want to play,in my code I get this name from a darabase:

```
private void btnAlarm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=cp1");
        cn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd1 = new OdbcCommand("select chemin from alarme where code_alarme=41", cn);
        cmd1.Connection = cn;
        fileName = cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        wave = new WaveOut();
        playAllAvailableDevices();
    }
```

Can you help me to find the solution please???? 
Thank you in advance.
Good day.

Comment: This is now the 5th question you have posted here on the same problem, plus several more queries on the NAudio website. We do want to help you but all the sample code you have posted so far shows you have a very limited grasp of C# and programming fundamentals. I strongly recommend you take some basic programming classes.

Comment: @ Mark Heath: Yes you have right,I have limited grasps of Csharp,and in the other threads I said that I'm a beginner.It's not the same problem,here I want to play sound in all the devices,the other questions are differents.Thank you for replying and I'm really sorry for bothering

Comment: Sorry if I offended you. We all need to start somewhere. I have updated my answer to include example code of how to play in all devices and also shown how you can improve your programming style a little to make use of functions rather than cut and paste code. Another issue with your code sample is that in btnAlarm1_Click you create another WaveOut object that is never used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the `DeviceNumber` property on the WaveOut object before calling `Init`. You could clean up your code a lot by using a simple function:

```
    private void PlaySoundInDevice(int deviceNumber, string fileName)
    {
        if (outputDevices.ContainsKey(deviceNumber))
        {
            outputDevices[deviceNumber].WaveOut.Dispose();
            outputDevices[deviceNumber].WaveStream.Dispose();
        }
        var waveOut = new WaveOut();
        waveOut.DeviceNumber = deviceNumber;
        WaveStream waveReader = new WaveFileReader(fileName);
        // hold onto the WaveOut and  WaveStream so we can dispose them later
        outputDevices[deviceNumber] = new PlaybackSession { WaveOut=waveOut, WaveStream=waveReader };

        waveOut.Init(waveReader);
        waveOut.Play();
    }

    private Dictionary<int, PlaybackSession> outputDevices = new Dictionary<int, PlaybackSession>();

    class PlaybackSession
    {
        public IWavePlayer WaveOut { get; set; }
        public WaveStream WaveStream { get; set; }
    }
```

The dictionary holds onto the WaveOut so it doesn't get garbage collected during playback, and allows us to clean up properly. Before you exit your application, make sure you clean up properly:

```
    private void DisposeAll()
    {
        foreach (var playbackSession in outputDevices.Values)
        {
            playbackSession.WaveOut.Dispose();
            playbackSession.WaveStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

And now you can play in all available devices using a for loop instead of your switch statement that requires you to duplicate code:

```
    public void PlayInAllAvailableDevices(string fileName)
    {
        int waveOutDevices = WaveOut.DeviceCount;
        for (int n = 0; n < waveOutDevices; n++)
        {
            PlaySoundInDevice(n, fileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Mark Heath: Thank you very much,I tried your code but it dont play sound in the three devices simultaneously,it's always waiting for only one device and I dont know why

Comment: What version of NAudio are you using?

Comment: I've just tested on my PC and it works fine. Although I'll make a small edit as the WaveOut object should not be a local variable or it will get disposed

Comment: Now it works very well,Thank you :) If you dont mind I want to ask you another question,Can I ?

Comment: I found in thecode project.com a function which give me the possibility to broadcast a streaming message.To be sincere I didn't understand very well the code but it plays sound with `private void Start()
  {
   Stop();
   try
   {
    WaveLib.WaveFormat fmt = new WaveLib.WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2);
    m_Player = new WaveLib.WaveOutPlayer(-1, fmt, 16384, 3, new WaveLib.BufferFillEventHandler(Filler));
    m_Recorder = new WaveLib.WaveInRecorder(-1, fmt, 16384, 3, new WaveLib.BufferDoneEventHandler(DataArrived));
   }
   catch
   {
    Stop();
    throw;
   }
  }`

Comment: this function works only in the default sound card and it didn't accept any external audio card,Can you tell me please how can I modify this code to oblige this function to read sound in an external sound card?

Comment: I would guess that the -1 parameters are the device number. Try replacing them with 0,1,2 etc

Comment: I changed it but I have always the same problem,when change -1 to 1 I can hear my voice from the default speaker,but when I write 2 or 3 I cant hear anything

Comment: well you would be best asking the author of that article then. You can use NAudio instead though. Use WaveOut instead of WaveOutPlayer and WaveIn instead of WaveInRecorder.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the BASS audio library:

http://www.un4seen.com/

This might also work:

http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio.aspx

I don't think C# is set up to do this without a third-party add-in like the ones listed above.  Maybe someone smarter than I can help you get it working but if not, these libraries will help you down the path you want.

Comment: @ Biggs TRC:Thank you very much for your help :)